# How to install python 3.4.3 from source and pip on Debian

Tags: python, linux, debian

I'm trying to setup a server on Debian with Python 3.4.3 and pip.

I installed python 3.4.3 from source into the /opt directory (is that the right one to install to?). I exported the /bin to path with

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/python3.4.3/bin"
```

but when I close the ssh, it doesn't work when I log back in.

And there isn't a scripts folder... so where is pip?

Comment: You don't want to use `apt-get`?

Comment: @Maltysen because it's python 3.2, and I wanted 3.4.3.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I think you can do `apt-get install python3.4`

Comment: "unable to locate package python3.4"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the line in which you export the `PATH` variable to the .profile and it will work after logging back in.

You can do this by executing

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/python3.4.3/bin"' >> ~/.profile
```

Instead of changing the `PATH` variable, you could simply install python into the system directories (where it is better placed), by going to the root of the source directory and running

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If pip is distributed within the python source, then it will be installed, too. Check if pip has been installed by executing

```
pip --version
```

If it is not, you have to manually install pip, too.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html explains how this is done.
Simply download the script `get-pip.py` and run it like this

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Comment: I've never used Debian before today, can you show steps? And can you answer the other things in the question?

Comment: echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/python3.4.3/bin'  >> ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 12):

Update (7/22/15): Use pyenv - it's a python version and virtual environment manager. For Debian, apt-get will get an old version, so it's better to use pyenv which installs from the source. You have to download Python dependencies to accomplish this: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems.

---

It appears `pip` is packaged in the python source.

To install Python 3.4.3 from source on Debian:

```
$ apt-get update 
$
$ cd /
$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
$
$ cd opt
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz
$ tar xzf Python-3.4.3.tgz
$
$ cd Python-3.4.3
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

To use:

```
$ python3
$ pip3
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your export is only working for the session you are. When you logout and then login, a new session is created. Just put `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/python3.4.3/bin"` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` and this will be executed everytime you login to a server.

And you can add the repositories for Debian testing and install python3.4 from there. This is what I have done in a Debian 7 server.

And pip lives in the bin/ directory.

Comment: I don't see pip in bin. There's 2to3, idle3, pydocs3, python3, pyvenv.

Comment: pip is a different program. It don't came in the python's default distribution. Here the install instructions: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

But I think the easiest way to do what you want is to use the repositories for debian jessie